# Can I compile a .c file to .exe file without a compiler?

Tags: c

I have recently downloaded an application file in the .c format. I want to convert it to an exe file so that i can run it. I also tried to download a compiler but I was unsuccessful. Can anyone help?

Comment: Without a compiler, it is impossible. "*I also tried to download a compiler but I was unsuccessful*" -- Could you tell us what you've done?

Comment: Try with friendly tools like PellesC

Comment: Your question sounds similar to "Can I print a document without a printer?"

Comment: If you want to run it, you're going to need more than just *any* C compiler. You need to find out whether it requires any special libraries and whether it uses calls specific to a particular platform. This information should be available form whom or where ever you obtained the source from.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Well, you can compile by hand: Re-write as assembler code, using the C code as a template and translate to machine language. Welcome to the 70ies home-computers. Use a hex-editor to create the binary (don't forget the management structures, though). But I think getting a compiler-tool to run is **way** easier.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 Home basic

Answer (score 3):

you could use an online complier such as [this website](http://www.onlinecompiler.net/)

Answer (score 0):

> Can I compile a .c file to .exe file without a compiler?

No